# set text view to view all elements in an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I create a dictionary that converts the values to an array. Printing the array to the log prints each value entry as each index in the array. Setting the `textview.text` to the same thing (each index in the array) prints only the first value.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var snippet: UITextView!

 var selectedDictionary = ["firstKey": "firstValue", "secondKey": "secondValue"]

 var selectedArray = [String] (selectedDictionary.values)
        var numberInArray = selectedArray.count
        for var i = 0; i < selectedArray.count; i++ {
            println(selectedArray[i])
            snippet.text = selectedArray[i]
```

Comment: // Asking a well-formatted *question* can be fruitful

Answer (score 3):

You can't iterate on each `selectedArray` value to update your TextView text property because every time the for loop finds a new value, this will show you only the last value in the Array.

Instead, you should try to build a String with all `selectedArray`'s values and then update the view text property.

You can do this:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var snippet: UITextView!
  var selectedDictionary = ["firstKey": "firstValue", "secondKey": "secondValue"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var text = ""
    var selectedArray = [String](selectedDictionary.values)
    for index in 0..<selectedArray.count {
      text += "\(selectedArray[index])\n"
    }

    snippet.text = text
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to appear identically to how it appears in the logs, use this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var snippet: UITextView!

var selectedDictionary = ["firstKey": "firstValue", "secondKey": "secondValue"]

snippet.text = String(format:"%@", selectedDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var snippet: UITextView!

 var selectedDictionary = ["firstKey": "firstValue", "secondKey": "secondValue"]

 var selectedArray = [String] (selectedDictionary.values)
 var numberInArray = selectedArray.count
 for var i = 0; i < selectedArray.count; i++ {
     println(selectedArray[i])
     snippet.text += selectedArray[i]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `String` for all values and then loop through your dictionary and append each value to the created String, after the loop is finished, you can update your `UITextView`.

```
weak var snippet: UITextView!
var selectedDictionary = ["firstKey": "firstValue", "secondKey": "secondValue"]
var allValues: String = ""

for value in selectedDictionary.values{
   if let v = value as String?{
      allValues += v
   }
}

//set the value of your textview to 'allValues'
```